# Rename all columns names by position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rename the columns of a DataFrame that has more than one hundred columns by their position (x1, x2, x3, etc.). I created the code below, but it is very inefficient. Is there a faster and better way of doing this in Pandas-Python?

```
for i, column_name in enumerate(df.columns.values):
     df.rename(columns={ df.columns[i]: "x" + str(i+1) }, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly assign to "df.columns".

```py
df.columns = [f'x{i+1}' for i in range(len(df.columns))]
```

Comment: Fix, df.columns = [f'x{i+1}' for i in range(len(df.columns))]

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
df.columns=np.arange(df.shape[1])+1
df=df.add_prefix('x')
```